# How might I introduce an expression in a struct definition in C?

Tags: c, struct, expression

I defined a struct:

```
struct Low {
     double high;
     double low;
     double fraction;   // = (Low.high - Low.low) / Low.high; 
     double percentage; // = Low.fraction * 100;  
} low2015, low2018, low2021, low2022;
```

The comments hint at what I am getting at.
I would like to introduce an expression in the definition block of the struct `Low` so that I do not have to manually do the assignment of `my_struct.fraction` and `my_struct.percentage`

```
low2021.high = 64854; 
low2021.low = 28805;
low2021.fraction = (low2021.high - low2021.low) / low2021.high;
low2021.percentage = low2021.fraction * 100;
```

for all the four variables, i.e. `low2015`, `low2018`, `low2021`, `low2022`.
How might I accomplish this?

Comment: C doesn't really work like that. Just define an `InitLow(struct Low *s, double a, double b)` function that does the appropriate initializations.

Comment: If you have such a fixed relations between struct fields, it is an indication that your data is redundant. So you might want to keep only the independent fields and calculate the others on demand only.

Comment: Do you need to store the two derived values?  Would you be better off with `struct MinLow { double high; double low; };` and then (static) inline functions to calculate fraction and percentage: `static inline double minlow_fraction(struct MinLow v) { return (v.high - v.low) / v.high; }` etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes so that I can do something like this:  `int main() {

low2015.high = 1128.4; 
low2015.low = 197.84 ;

double fraction = minlow_fraction(low2015); 
double percentage = minlow_percentage(low2015); 
printf("The all-time high of $%.1lf for Bitcoin was followed by the drop of %.1lf%%.\n", low2015.high, percentage );
return 0; 
}`

Comment: Yes, along those lines.  Use the functions when you need the derived values.  It guarantees that the calculation is correct at the time of call, even if something has changed the `low` or `high` value since the values in the original `fraction` and `percentage` members were recalculated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The structure is small enough to be returned by value. Consider adding a function `MakeLow()`.

```
struct Low {
     double high;
     double low;
     double fraction;
     double percentage;
};

static inline struct Low MakeLow(double high, double low) {
    return (struct Low) {
      .high = high,
      .low = low,
      .fraction = (high - low) / high,
      .percentage = (high - low) / high * 100,
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
struct Low low2021 = MakeLow(64854, 28805);
```

Comment: You've taught an old dog a new trick... I didn't know you could do an anonymous structure like that.

Comment: @SGeorgiades This is not an anonymous struct, this is a *compound literal*.